# How to paginate MySQL Aurora DB query using TypeScript?

Tags: mysql, typescript, amazon-aurora, mysql2

I am using an API gateway which is connected to a lambda function in Restful API.

I successfully access my normal aurora(MySQL) DB and able to query data from the data base and return the results.
Currently , I want to apply pagination but I'm not sure how can I paginate my query.

Notes:

- Using typescript
- Node18
- Using MySQL2 package

Answer (score 0):

Is your question about how to retrieve page N of results, like rows 10-20? Because that is purely in how you code your SQL with the LIMIT and OFFSET clauses. See https://www.linuxscrew.com/mysql-limit-offset

If the question is how to know whether the call to the Lambda function needs to retrieve page 1, page 2, or some other page, usually that's a parameter in the RESTful API and gets passed in the query string for the link to "next page".